# Tab-complete a parameter value based on another parameter's already specified value

Tags: powershell, dynamic, tab-completion

This question addresses the following scenario:

- Can custom tab-completion for a given command dynamically determine completions based on the value previously passed to *another* parameter on the same command line, using either a parameter-level [`[ArgumentCompleter()]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ArgumentCompleterAttribute) *attribute* or the [`Register-ArgumentCompleter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/register-argumentcompleter) *cmdlet*?
- If so, what are the limitations of this approach?

Example scenario:

A hypothetical `Get-Property` command has an `-Object` parameter that accepts an object of any type, and a `-Property` parameter that accepts the name of a property whose value to extract from the object.

Now, in the course of typing a `Get-Property` call, if a value is already specified for `-Object`, tab-completing `-Property` should cycle through the names of the specified object's (public) properties.

```
$obj = [pscustomobject] @{ foo = 1; bar = 2; baz = 3 }

Get-Property -Object $obj -Property # <- pressing <tab> here should cycle
                                    # through 'foo', 'bar', 'baz'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@mklement0, regarding first limitation stated in [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65892519/2824685)

> The custom-completion script block (`{ ... }`) invoked by PowerShell fundamentally **only sees values specified via *parameters*, not via the pipeline**.

I struggled with this, and after some stubbornness I got a working solution.
At least good enough for my tooling, and I hope it can make life easier for many others out there.

This solution has been verified to work with PowerShell versions `5.1` and `7.1.2`.

Here I made use of `$cmdAst` (called `$commandAst` in the docs), which contains information about the pipeline. With this we can get to know the previous pipeline *element* and even differentiate between it containing only a variable or a command. Yes, A COMMAND, which with help of `Get-Command` and the command's `OutputType()` member method, we can get (suggested) property names for such as well!

### Example usage

```
PS> $obj = [pscustomobject] @{ foo = 1; bar = 2; baz = 3 }
PS> $obj | Get-Property -Property # <tab>: bar, baz, foo
PS> "la", "na", "le" | Select-String "a" | Get-Property -Property # <tab>: Chars, Context, Filename, ...
PS> 2,5,2,2,6,3 | group | Get-Property -Property # <tab>: Count, Values, Group, ...
```

### Function code

Note that apart from now using `$cmdAst`, I also added `[Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]` so we actually pick the object, and `PROCESS {$Object.$Property}` so that one can test and see the code actually working.

```
param(
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
    [object] $Object,
    [ArgumentCompleter({
        param($cmdName, $paramName, $wordToComplete, $cmdAst, $preBoundParameters)
        # Find out if we have pipeline input.
        $pipelineElements = $cmdAst.Parent.PipelineElements
        $thisPipelineElementAsString = $cmdAst.Extent.Text
        $thisPipelinePosition = [array]::IndexOf($pipelineElements.Extent.Text, $thisPipelineElementAsString)
        $hasPipelineInput = $thisPipelinePosition -ne 0

        $possibleArguments = @()
        if ($hasPipelineInput) {
            # If we are in a pipeline, find out if the previous pipeline element is a variable or a command.
            $previousPipelineElement = $pipelineElements[$thisPipelinePosition - 1]
            $pipelineInputVariable = $previousPipelineElement.Expression.VariablePath.UserPath
            if (-not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($pipelineInputVariable)) {
                # If previous pipeline element is a variable, get the object.
                # Note that it can be a non-existent variable. In such case we simply get nothing.
                $detectedInputObject = Get-Variable |
                    Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $pipelineInputVariable} |
                        ForEach-Object Value
            } else {
                $pipelineInputCommand = $previousPipelineElement.CommandElements[0].Value
                if (-not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($pipelineInputCommand)) {
                    # If previous pipeline element is a command, check if it exists as a command.
                    $possibleArguments += Get-Command -CommandType All |
                        Where-Object Name -Match "^$pipelineInputCommand$" |
                            # Collect properties for each documented output type.
                            ForEach-Object {$_.OutputType.Type} | ForEach-Object GetProperties |
                                # Group properties by Name to get unique ones, and sort them by
                                # the most frequent Name first. The sorting is a perk.
                                # A command can have multiple output types. If so, we might now
                                # have multiple properties with identical Name.
                                Group-Object Name -NoElement | Sort-Object Count -Descending |
                                    ForEach-Object Name
                }
            }
        } elseif ($preBoundParameters.ContainsKey("Object")) {
            # If not in pipeline, but object has been given, get the object.
            $detectedInputObject = $preBoundParameters["Object"]
        }
        if ($null -ne $detectedInputObject) {
            # The input object might be an array of objects, if so, select the first one.
            # We (at least I) are not interested in array properties, but the object element's properties.
            if ($detectedInputObject -is [array]) {
                $sampleInputObject = $detectedInputObject[0]
            } else {
                $sampleInputObject = $detectedInputObject
            }
            # Collect property names.
            $possibleArguments += $sampleInputObject | Get-Member -MemberType Properties | ForEach-Object Name
        }
        # Refering to about_Functions_Argument_Completion documentation.
        #   The ArgumentCompleter script block must unroll the values using the pipeline,
        #   such as ForEach-Object, Where-Object, or another suitable method.
        #   Returning an array of values causes PowerShell to treat the entire array as one tab completion value.
        $possibleArguments | Where-Object {$_ -like "$wordToComplete*"}
    })]
    [string] $Property
)

PROCESS {$Object.$Property}
```

Comment: Well done, @betoz. Looking at the _parent_ of the AST that is passed to the completer hadn't even occurred to me.

Comment: @mklement0, I was annoyed by tab-completion returning names of files and directories in the case of `ArgumentCompleter` script block return nothing, e.g. when no detected object, or when previous command in pipeline had empty `OutputType`.

I found out that adding attribute `[ArgumentCompletions('')]` (notice empty string) results in no tab-completion in the case of `ArgumentCompleter` script block returning nothing.

However, this attribute was introduced in PowerShell `6.0`.
I confirmed this to work with PowerShell `7.1.2`, and to not work with `5.1`.

Comment: Understood. Please see https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7215 and https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14147

Answer (score 2):

**Update**: **See [betoz's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74766060/45375)** for a more complete solution that also supports *pipeline input*.

The part of the answer below that clarifies the limitations of pre-execution detection of the input objects' data type still applies.

---

The following solution uses a parameter-specific `[ArgumentCompleter()]` attribute as part of the definition of the `Get-Property` function itself, but the solution analogously applies to separately defining custom-completion logic via the `Register-CommandCompleter` cmdlet.

**Limitations**:

- [*See [betoz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74766060/45375) for how to overcome this limitation*] The custom-completion script block (`{ ... }`) invoked by PowerShell fundamentally **only sees values specified via *parameters*, not *via the pipeline***.

  - That is, if you type `Get-Property -Object $obj -Property <tab>`, the script block can determine that the value of `$obj` is to be bound to the `-Object` parameter, but that wouldn't work with
    `$obj | Get-Property -Property <tab>` (even if `-Object` is declared as pipeline-binding).
- Fundamentally, **only values that can be evaluated *without side effects* are actually accessible** in the script block; in concrete terms, this means:

  - *Literal* values (e.g., `-Object ([pscustomobject] @{ foo = 1; bar = 2; baz = 3 })`
  - *Simple variable references* (e.g., `-Object $obj`) or *property-access*  or *index-access* expressions (e.g., `-Object $obj.Foo` or `-Object $obj[0]`)
  - Notably, the following values are *not* accessible:

    - *Method*-call results (e.g., `-Object $object.Foo()`)
    - *Command* output (via `(...)`, `$(...)`, or `@(...)`, e.g.
      `-Object (Invoke-RestMethod http://example.org)`)
    - The reason for this limitation is that evaluating such values *before* actually submitting the command could have undesirable side effects and / or could take a long time to complete.

```
function Get-Property {

  param(

    [object] $Object,

    [ArgumentCompleter({

      # A fixed list of parameters is passed to an argument-completer script block.
      # Here, only two are of interest:
      #  * $wordToComplete: 
      #      The part of the value that the user has typed so far, if any.
      #  * $preBoundParameters (called $fakeBoundParameters 
      #    in the docs):
      #      A hashtable of those (future) parameter values specified so 
      #      far that are side effect-free (see above).
      param($cmdName, $paramName, $wordToComplete, $cmdAst, $preBoundParameters)

        # Was a side effect-free value specified for -Object?
        if ($obj = $preBoundParameters['Object']) {

          # Get all property names of the objects and filter them
          # by the partial value already typed, if any, 
          # interpreted as a name prefix.
          @($obj.psobject.Properties.Name) -like "$wordToComplete*"

        }
      })]
    [string] $Property

  )

  # ...

}
```